# Look for a dynamically added class on template

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have hard time figuring out how to detect a class dynamically added on HTML template:

Template:

```html
<div class="one two" [class.hide]="hide$ | push">...</div>
```

Component:

```typescript
hide$ = combineLatest(...); // basically returns true or false
```

Test:

```typescript
      it('should show class hide if hide Observable is true', fakeAsync(() => {

         const el = ngMocks.find('.one');

         expect(el.nativeNode.classList).toContain('one');
         expect(el.nativeNode.classList).toContain('hide');

         component.hide$.subscribe(d => {
            expect(d).toEqual(true);
         });
      }))
```

When I subscribe to hide$ `expect(d).toEqual(true);` does get passed. Which means value is true. But I also want to write test `.toContain('hide');`. But I can't figure out how to get an updated classList from the element.

Comment: You need to simulate the behavior. The key is to trigger change detection manually after the Observable emits a new value. So, you need to create a mock observable that emits a value and completes. This can be done using the operator ```of()```, i think.